# Merge [jquery-datepicker] and [jquery-ui-datepicker]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Could someone please merge the tags [jquery-datepicker](/questions/tagged/jquery-datepicker) and [jquery-ui-datepicker](/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-datepicker)? They quite obviously are exact duplicates.

The full name of the plugin is [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), so I would have [jquery-ui-datepicker](/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-datepicker) as the main tag.

Comment: Looks like the tags have been merged. Feel free to tag `completed`.